# Points not showing up in Threejs

Tags: three.js, points, particle-system

I am trying to use Points object in threejs. I am trying to display a point, but it is not showing up. Browser does not give any error. Let me know what needs to be done. Thanks

```js
let pointGeometry:any = new BufferGeometry();
let positionAttribute = new BufferAttribute( new Float32Array([10,5,10]), 10 );
pointGeometry.setAttribute( 'position', positionAttribute );
pointGeometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
pointGeometry.setDrawRange(0,10);
let pointMaterial = new PointsMaterial( { color: 0x03F9E7, size: 10 } );
this.point = new Points( pointGeometry, pointMaterial );
this.point.name = 'point';
this.point.scale.copy( new Vector3(10,10,10) );
this.scene.add( this.point );
```

Comment: `new BufferAttribute( new Float32Array([10,5,10]), 10 )`, why is it `10` for item size, it has to be 3. And this line `this.point.scale.copy( new Vector3(10,10,10) );`, it can be just `this.point.scale.setScalar( 10 );`

Answer (score 0):

The `itemSize` of `BufferAttribute` should be `3`.

```js
let positionAttribute = new BufferAttribute( new Float32Array([10,5,10]), 3 );
pointGeometry.setAttribute( 'position', positionAttribute );
```

> `itemSize` -- the number of values of the array that should be associated with a particular vertex. For instance, if this attribute is storing a 3-component vector (such as a position, normal, or color), then itemSize should be 3.

[[Docs] BufferAttribute](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferAttribute)

Another reason may be that the camera looks to the wrong position. If you set a scale of `10` the final position of the point will be at `[100,50,100]`.